# Why prepared statement in jdbc in jsp program is returning null value

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

As a part of my project, I started a student monitoring system. As a part of this, I want to insert the student details into the database.  I want to insert entered details into database using a prepared statement. In this process I faced this issue. How to solve?

The code is as follows.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
    <body bgcolor = "pink">
        <%!
            Connection con;
            PreparedStatement ps;
            public void jspInit()
            {
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","sai");
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into list(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                }
                catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
            }
        %>
        <%
            String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
            String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
            String ID = request.getParameter("ID");
            String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
            String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
        %>
            <h2 align = "center"><font color = "red">Your Entered Details::</font></h2>
            <table align = "center" border = "1px solid black" cellspacing = "2px" cellpadding="5px">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Field</b></td>
                    <td><b>data</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Firstname</b> </td>
                    <td><%=firstname%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Lastname</b></td>
                    <td><%=lastname%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Student ID</b></td>
                    <td><%=ID%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Gender   </b></td>
                    <td><%=gender%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Phone </b></td>
                    <td><%=phone%></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Email</b></td>
                    <td><%=email%> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <%
            try
            {
                
                ps.setString(1,firstname);
                ps.setString(2,lastname);
                ps.setString(3,ID);
                ps.setString(4,gender);
                ps.setString(5,phone);
                ps.setString(6,email);
                int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                if(i>0)
                {
                    out.println("<h3 align = 'center'><font color = 'red'>successfully registered</font></h3>");
                    out.println("<h4 align = 'center'>Click here to.! -> <a href='http://localhost:9999/kaushik/index.html'>Go back</a></h4>");
                }
                else
                {
                     out.println("<h3 align = 'center'><font color = 'red'>Unable to register</font></h3>");
                     out.println("<h4 align = 'center'>please try again.! -> <a href='http://localhost:9999/kaushik/insert.html'> click here</a></h4>");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){out.println("An exception occurred: " + ex);}
        %>
        <%!
            public void jspDestroy()
            {
                try
                {
                    ps.close();
                    con.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think the is no problem in the variables set (firstname, lastname, etc.) as those values are successfully being displayed in the table.
So, the `ps.setString(...)` is not working because `ps` is set to null. I created the table in Oracle database. How to solve this issue? What is the error in my program?

Comment: You should definitely remove all those snippets, and start using servlets.

Comment: Are you looking at the log output? Shouldn't the SQL be `insert into list values (...`

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the error messages; "program does not work" is very far from a useful error description … But the comment from @tgdavies should give you a hint already on what is wrong with your code. And your program should never proceed after an exception when you have not remediated the reason for that exception! Printing the stacktrace is not solving an issue!!!

Comment: See hints above for SQL. Note that putting some variables in class scope `<%! ...  %>` means your JSP is not thread-safe as the connection + statement variables would be visible to and accessed by simultaneous callers. Obviously this isn't an issue for homework but it is serious flaw if this technique is used in live system.

Comment: You're swallowing exceptions and then continue on as if nothing happens. If you get an exception loading the driver class or creating the connection, `con` and `ps` will be null, if you get an exception creating the statement, `ps` will be `null`. Check your logs for errors.